# Equation of line in 3d space passing in two points in a form of ax+by+cz+d=0

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d, parametric

I'm sorry for asking probably such easy question, but need help with this..
I need to get the parameters with the equation of a straight line passing through two points in 3d space.

ex:

```
line passes through
point1 (x1,y1,z1) point2 (x2,y2,z2)
```

I need the final equation in this parametric form

```
ax + by + cz + d = 0
```

I need to get **a**, **b**, **c**, and **d** parameters.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3d space your equation describes a **plane**, not a line.

The usual parametric form for a line would be $\vec{x} + t\vec{w}$, for $t$ a scalar, say.

In your case you can take $\vec{v} = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and 
$\vec{w} = (x_2,y_2,z_2) - (x_1,y_1,z_1)$ e.g.

Comment: if it was a plane, how would it be?

Comment: @Cayenne two points do not determine a plane.

Comment: @Cayenne but $\vec{x} + t\vec{w} + u\vec{z}$ is a parametric form of a plane. And $ax + by +cy +d=0$ is an "equational" form.

Comment: so ax + by + cz + d = 0 is for a plane and not a line.. its not like a linear line ax + by + c = 0 in  2d?

Comment: @Cayenne no, one linear equation "takes away" one dimension from the whole space, so in 2d it is a line, in 3d a plane, in 4d a three-dimenional hyperplane.

Comment: okay thanks this explains the confusion...